# How to create a regular expression to match non-consecutive characters?

Tags: regex

How to create a regular expression for strings of `a`,`b` and `c` such that `aa` and `bb` will be rejected?

For example, `abcabccababcccccab` will be accepted and `aaabc` or `aaabbcccc` or `abcccababaa` will be rejected.

Comment: It would be easier to search for `aa` and `bb` and invert your decision.

Comment: Is this homework, by the way?

Answer (score 4):

If this is not a purely academical question you can simply search for `aa` and `bb` and negate your logic, for example:

```
s='abcccabaa'
# continue if string does not match.
if re.search('(?:aa|bb)', s) is None:
    ...
```

or simply scan the string for the two patterns, **avoiding expensive regular expressions**:

```
if 'aa' not in s and 'bb' not in s:
    ...
```

For such an easy task RE is probably total overkill.

*P.S.: The examples are in Python but the principle applies to other languages of course.*

Comment: +1 for suggesting non-regex solutions. The string-scanning solution is much easier to understand, and quite likely faster as well.

Comment: Yes, the option of not using RE is often not considered. An ionteresting question would be in which cases what is faster.

Comment: Compiled regular expressions are often faster than you think, depending on the amount of backtracking required. If you can replace a bunch of string operations with a single regular expression, without the regex needing to backtrack for anything, the regex will actually be *faster* than the string operations.

Comment: I think the OP means he has strings that are formed like `[abc]*` and he wants to exclude those with `aa` and `bb`. So I don't think it needs to be checked if they have this form. If yes then `re` might be necessary.

Comment: Agree with Li-aung. At some point, a single regex will be faster than string operations, especially for a very large input that evacuates your computer's caches. E.g. will almost certainly be faster to pass a 10 megabyte string through your CPU once (with a well-cached regex machine), than to repeatedly scan it several times. The memory bandwidth can become the bottleneck.  A smart regex implementation doesn't do any backtracking. (Not for anything that is truly regular.)

Comment: I agree that at some point `re` needs to be faster -- after all it wouldn't make sense to scan the whole string for a list of 20 different pattern strings that are disallowed. The `re` automaton most likely collapses those into a decision graph that is more efficient. But for one or two patterns and smaller strings the direct search should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Using the & operator (intersection) and ~ (complement):

```
(a|b|c)*&~(.*(aa|cc).*)
```

Rewriting this without the these operators is tricky. The usual approach is to break it into cases.

In this case it is not all that difficult.

Suppose that the letter `c` is taken out of the picture. The only sequences then which don't have `aa` and `bb` are:

```
e (empty string)
a
b
b?(ab)*a?
```

Next what we can do is insert some optional 'c' runs into all possible interior places:

```
e (empty string)
a
b
(bc*)?(ac*bc*)*a?
```

Next, we have to acknowledge that illegal sequences like `aabb` become accepted if non-optional 'c' runs are put in the middle, as in for example `acacbcbc'. We allow a final`a`and`b`. This pattern can take care of our lone`a`and`b` cases as well as matching the empty string:

```
(ac+|bc+)*(a|b)?
```

Then combine them together:

```
((ac+|bc+)*(a|b)?|(bc*)?(ac*bc*)*a?|(ac+|bc+)(a|b)?)
```

We are almost there: we also need to recognize that this pattern can occur an arbitrary number of times, as long as there are dividing 'c'-s between the occurences, and with arbitrary leading or trailing runs of `c`-s around the whole thing

```
c*((ac+|bc+)*(a|b)?|(bc*)?(ac*bc*)*a?|(ac+|bc+)(a|b)?)(c+((ac+|bc+)*(a|b)?|(bc*)?(ac*bc*)*a?|(ac+|bc+)(a|b)?))*c*
```

Mr. Regex Philbin, I'm not coming up with any cases that this doesn't handle, so I'm leaving it as my final answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?!.*(?:aa|bb))[abc]+$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30fk2)

This regex would do two things

1. verify that your string consist only of a,b and c
2. fail on aa and bb

`^` matches the start of the string

`(?!.*(?:aa|bb))` [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), will fail if there is aa or bb in the string

`[abc]+` [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), allows only a,b,c at least one (`+`)

`$` matches the end of the string

Comment: I don't think this Perl cruft qualifies as a regular expression.

Comment: Why do you think so? This is a perfectly valid perl regular expression. Maybe you should have a look at the modern power of perl regex: [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).